# Migrating a C# windows service to Mac

Tags: c#, macos, service

We have a C# server that is registered as a service on windows and I want to run it on my Mac (10.7.3).

I have installed MonoFramework, and tried to run the executable via command line (mono xxx.exe) and got fatal error.

I realized that since it is supposed to be a service, there is some code that does the actual registration. There is a .bat file that registers it.

1. Is there a magical way where I can run it and it will simply work? (guess not)
2. Since I have the source code, what should be my next step(s)?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the fatal error you are getting.

Comment: Kind of hard to imagine a windows service running on a Mac, actually. Maybe you could tell us more about how it works, though? What sort of service are we talking about?